# How to enable insecure content for automating downloading pds using selenium for python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to enable autodownloading of pdfs using selenium for python. However, while I have enabled auto-download of the pdfs, the pdfs themselves are not actually downloading. The reason for this is because I need to allow for insecure content from the url. Because this is not happening, the autodownloading is not happening and there is just a grey screen. I looked at some posts and have added some options to enable insecure content but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "/Users/xxxx/DownloadedPDFs", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True, #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
"safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
"safebrowsing.enabled": False
})

chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)



driver.get("url") 
# there is an actual url here, I just put URL as a placeholder 

time.sleep(10)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("annualreports_link")
for element in elements: 
    element.click()
```

What I do know is that the pdfs do get downloaded to a separate folder properly if the url gets added to insecure content and the setting for that can be found here when clicking for Insecure content for site settings:

[Url needs to get added to show insecure content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GruCb.png)

Comment: I had twice this problem with cUrl in a Ubuntu Server. The first I solved downloading the certificate and adding it to the trusted certificates list of my server. The second had a self signed certificate, and I didn't manage to get it working, but then I realised the website was accepting connections at por 80, so I just changed to http instead of https.